# if else route on ajax data not working

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

In the javascript below. the like_add function takes the else route. intead of taking the if route. even though it returns success. so my question is why? the data returns success but it doesnt move to the like_get function, instead it alerts(data) success.

```
function like_add(id){
    $.post('ajax/like_add.php',{id:id},function(data){
        if(data == "success"){
            like_get(id);
        }else{
            alert(data);
        }
     });
 }

 function like_get(id){
     $.post('ajax/like_get.php',{id:id},function(data){
         $('#post_'+ id +'_likes').text(data);
     });
 }
```

Comment: are you sure you gettting "success" in the ajax response ?

Comment: what are you returning from your server.. ALso can you do a console.log(data) and let us know what you see.

Comment: Please do a `console.log(data)` and paste its output.

Comment: i am know i am getting success because the alert says success. in the console it says POST ajax/like_add.php response success POST id=6

Comment: can you try specifying the return type.. by adding one more parameter "text" to post thus $.post(...,function(){},"text");

Comment: specifying text return type didnt work. i did {},"text");

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try to trim data first , it's probably some space or hidden characters which you can see on the alert

```
data = $.trim(data);
```

also alert data length so you can be sure

```
else{
    alert(data);
    alert(data.length);
    }
```

Comment: that is very interesting. when i alerted for length it alerted 11. even though the success is seven chracters. so after i trimmed the data, it worked properly. so my question is, what was causing all this extra space? what a relief, i have spent around 5 hours trying to fix this.

Comment: i'm not sure when or why these white spaces are coming along but if i had to guess i would say it could be backend page encoding , you can also use json to pass data

Comment: The HTTP protocol does include several new lines in its response. I would think jquery would strip at least some of them off, but perhaps not. In any case, although the trim was a reasonable position, you also could have used the indexOf function to see if "success" was located at position 0.