# passing string using ajax when done

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I'm trying incorporate some if-else statements with ajax

So basically I have this php file `get.php` and another php file (with the ajax code) `ajax.php`

my ajax looks something like this. This is `ajax.php`

```
$.ajax({ 
    type: "GET",
    data: data,
    url: "get.php"

}).done(function(data){
    alert(data);
    if(data == "homer"){
        alert("doh");
    }else if(data == "wife"){
        alert("marge");
    }

});
```

I have some php script, this is `get.php`

```
if(!$something){
echo "homer";
}else{
echo "wife";
}
```

So basically, I'm getting the appropriate `alert(data)`, which is either homer or wife. But its not alerting `doh` or `marge`

Can someone explain why this is not working?

Thank you!

Comment: confused with get.php, ajax.php & one.php...! don't you?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

http adds some white spaces to the data so you have to trim it first

[if else route on ajax data not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10165359/if-else-route-on-ajax-data-not-working/10165525#10165525)